SonarQube Warning #2259: foreach(T object.ICollection<T>) shows warning "is null on at least one execution path"
SonarQube Warning# S2259 is null on at least one execution path
I have this C# code below. Why item.Children is showing a SonarQube Warning# S2259. We don't want to use suppress/pragma to exempt the warning. Any help to fix the warning is really appreciated. Thank you in advance.
private void ProcessData(ICollection data)
{
    foreach(IData item in data)
    {
        //item.Children is showing SonarQube Warning# S2259
        foreach(ICollection child in item.Children)
        {
        }
    }
}

